# Print Google Workspace Gmail Address lists in GAM

Tags: open-source, google-workspace, google-admin-sdk

I would like to know, is there any way to print using GAM the entire Gmail address lists (and their contents) found on the Admin console by going to 'Apps'> 'Google Workspace'> 'Gmail'> 'Routing'> 'Manage address lists'?

I have researched on GAM but so far no clear ways on how to do it. I have also tried exporting the page as HTML code and then using regex but not very time efficient

Comment: should be able to get it out of google contacts.   Check people api.

Comment: What's GAM ?...

Comment: GAM = Google Apps Manager https://github.com/GAM-team/GAM/wiki